# Red dot when review queue is empty

Tags: support

Several times now I have seen a red dot on the left of an item in the review queue drop-down menu, but when I click on that item, I am told the queue is empty. So why am I seeing a red dot, which I thought meant "review needed"?

[image: Red dot and empty queues]

Comment: Just a guess: The queue still has entries, but you cannot see them, probably because you already have reviewed those items.

Comment: I also experienced that frequently and I also wondered why this happens. This dot somewhat urges me to do something about although I cannot...

Comment: @bbgodfrey. I think you might be right, but if that is the case, shouldn't it be considered a bug?

Comment: I sometimes still get the red dot if I skip reviewing items. Very odd.

Comment: see [Experiment: Review-needed indicator logic for sites that sometimes have empty queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/346882) and links therein.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform. I don't think the question you link to explains what I'm experiencing. I don't see only red dots. More often I see gray dots which indicate that some queues are not empty but are not in dire need of attention. When I click on a gray dot marked item, the indicated queue has always opened for review.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay.  I believe that, once you "skip" an item, you no longer can view it.

Comment: This is still an issue. All the possible explanations mentioned don't seem to indicate a desirable behaviour. If my queue is empty, why would I need a red dot indicator? Am I supposed to go to the chat and start pressuring people to review their own queues? No, I think this is a bug.